# Remove All Unwanted js and css files from theme

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I create a website based on Drupal. When I look at the JavaScript and CSS files loaded from Drupal, I see many unwanted files loaded. I want to force Drupal to load only those files added to the .info file and remove everything else. I think I can achieve it by using `hook_js_alter()` but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: hook_js_alter and hook_css_alter are reliable ways

Comment: @rémy I think so, I can first unset all js(css) data then add theme js(css) files. I ask here maybe another guys has better idea

Comment: these files are served from drupal and (maybe) your super-theme. there is no other way, except chancing code which you should not touch. with this _alter methods your are totally upgrade save !

Comment: Removing CSS and Javascript could cause modules not to work properly.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know that, in this project we try to work MVC, just use drupal as CMSF and pass data to view layer, so in view layer not need any module js and css

Comment: @zhilevan I don;t know the acronym CMSF and quick search did not get me any results. What does it mean?

Comment: @J.Reynolds Drupal is a content management system framework not only  a CMS ;)

Comment: @zhilevan In that case I suppose the answer depends on whether your outer MVC template relies on htm.tpl.php or not, and if not if you need to manage your resources via the MVC framework and cycle through the drupal js files via hook_js_alter(). If your view is totally independent of Drupal's theming system then you could just manually add the same files found in the theme's ini file to the MVC framework's resource manager.

Comment: @J.Reynolds my idea is , in hook_js_alter unset all js file except only that added to theme (also for style), but I ask my question here maybe another one has another idea or experience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal only has one sanctioned mechanism for removing specific assets, regardless of the motivation for doing so.

For CSS:

[`hook_css_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7)

For JS:

[`hook_js_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7)

**To remove all style and scripts except `.info` style and script use below codes:**

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
    $themes=list_themes();
          foreach($css as $key=>$item) {
            if (!in_array($key, $themes['yourthemename']->stylesheets['all'])) {
                unset($css[$key]);
            }
        }
}



function hook_js_alter(&$js) {
    $themes=list_themes();
    foreach($js as $key=>$item) {
        if (!in_array($key, $themes['yourthemename']->scripts)) {
            unset($js[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

If the theme/module is custom, then obviously you can just remove the offending code manually if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Dear Clive, I implemented it today and for to be sure I ask here, I had another idea about doing this job, in `html.tpl.php`  comment <?print $scripts`($css)?> and add my theme JS (CSS) files in there .

Comment: @zhilevan If you you do that, I don't believe aggregation or any of the other fancy stuff that can happen with CSS and JS will happen.

Comment: If you are getting errors about `missing objects` using @Clive's code, it's because you likely don't have any CSS or JS files defined in your theme's `.info` file.

Just define at least one JS (or CSS) file to prevent the error:

`scripts[] = yourthemejsfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

This code works for removing the CSS from frontend:

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

Just use the above in yourtheme.info.yml